# Almost complete connectivity blackout

Tags: proxy, linux-mint, connection

I am running a Mint 13 XFCE machine and, seemingly out of nowhere found myself with "Server not found" pages in Firefox. However the blackout is not complete; at least one domain is reachable.

A few extra curiosities:

- I could through Thunderbird connect to *some* imap email servers (but not all) through port 993.
- Seemingly the only page I can ping is `berkeley.edu`. All others I have tried say `host unknown`. (In fact, the mail server that Thunderbird can reach is on the `berkeley.edu` domain)
- When at Berkeley today, connectivity was fine after 15 minutes or so. Back home, the issue remains.

Here are the things I tried:

- Restarting
- Checking the router from another device (ok)
- I used to connect through a proxy server (automatic configuration URL) but disabled that as the first try to restore connectivity.
- Connecting with a wire to the router

My firewall is off. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I hacked it by removing /etc/resolv.conf and I am back online for the moment.